# How to dynamically detect languages in javascript

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

Here I am trying to auto detect voice and try to search. which i can able to do.

But my problem is, in my code it's not auto detecting the languages.

**example:**

let a voice is speeked in English and it'll auto detect the letter and search in English language. (Let speak - Hello, search text - Hello)

Let say, a voice is spoken in Hindi and it'll auto-detect the letter and search in Hindi language. (Let speak - नहीं, search text - नहीं)

> I think my problem is in recognition.lang = "hi-IN"; code. here i need
>   to pass multiple laguages for auto detect.
>
> So anyone can help me on this?

```
<html>
<!-- CSS Styles -->
<style>
  .speech {border: 1px solid #DDD; width: 300px; padding: 0; margin: 0}
  .speech input {border: 0; width: 240px; display: inline-block; height: 30px;}
  .speech img {float: right; width: 40px }
</style>

<!-- Search Form -->
<form id="labnol" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <div class="speech">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="transcript" placeholder="Speak" />
    <img onclick="startDictation()" src="//i.imgur.com/cHidSVu.gif" />
  </div>
</form>

<!-- HTML5 Speech Recognition API -->
<script>
  function startDictation() {

    if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition')) {

      var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

      recognition.continuous = false;
      recognition.interimResults = false;

      recognition.lang = "hi-IN";
      recognition.start();

      recognition.onresult = function(e) {
        document.getElementById('transcript').value
                                 = e.results[0][0].transcript;
        recognition.stop();
        document.getElementById('labnol').submit();
      };

      recognition.onerror = function(e) {
        recognition.stop();
      }

    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I have never used the SpeechRecognition API before but from what I read about it, perhaps creating multiple instances of the recognition object each initialised to a different language might help. Using a little bit of heuristics/brute force, you can always capture events from all instances, eliminate `nomatch` cases and compare their results based on confidence to select the best one. [Leaving this as a comment for now as it is an untested hypothesis. Will add an answer when I get the chance to work out a PoC which works]

Comment: @ChiragRavindra do you have any other aproach or any other api to get similar functionality ?

Comment: No, sorry.. I have not worked on speech detection before. Will definitely explore and revert if I find something

Comment: @ChiragRavindra thank you